# Reading messages from Gmail, in PHP, using Gmail API

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I have donwloaded new Gmail API source code from Google PHP client library.

I inititalized the service using:

```php
set_include_path("./google-api-php-client-master/src/".PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
    
require_once 'Google/Client.php';   
require_once 'Google/Service/Gmail.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($this->config->item('gmailapi_clientid'));
$client->setClientSecret($this->config->item('gmailapi_clientsecret'));
$client->setRedirectUri(base_url('auth'));
$client->addScope('email');
//$client->addScope('profile');     
$client->addScope('https://mail.google.com');           
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$gmailService = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
```

What should I do next? How to read Gmail messages using Gmail API PHP library?

Answer (score 25):

For the sake of demonstration, you can do something like this:

```php
$optParams = [];
$optParams['maxResults'] = 5; // Return Only 5 Messages
$optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox
$messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$optParams);
$list = $messages->getMessages();
$messageId = $list[0]->getId(); // Grab first Message


$optParamsGet = [];
$optParamsGet['format'] = 'full'; // Display message in payload
$message = $service->users_messages->get('me',$messageId,$optParamsGet);
$messagePayload = $message->getPayload();
$headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
$parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();

$body = $parts[0]['body'];
$rawData = $body->data;
$sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
$decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);

var_dump($decodedMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks lot. is possible to get message details using listUersMessages() function. Because its very slow when loading first twenty messages with message details

Comment: Thanks a lot, it miss me sanitizedData can you explain why we must do that ?

Comment: @Jean-LucBarat, I found a better explanation than what I would have come up with. Credit goes to joesmo
There are additional base64 specs. But essentially you need 65 chars to encode: 26 lowercase + 26 uppercase + 10 digits = 62.

You need two more ['+', '/'] and a padding char '='. But none of them are url friendly, so just use different chars for them and you're set. The standard ones from the chart above are ['-', '_'], but you could use other chars as long as you decoded them the same, and didn't need to share with others.

Comment: Thanks nice explanation.

Comment: Oooh!!! Thank you! But i don't understand. Why  `$sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');` is not included in php client module?

Comment: It is not included in the PHP Client Module. I may be wrong though but will verify.

Comment: $body = $parts[0]['body']; this line is throwing error. What does it mean?
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\xampp\htdocs\gmailAPI\quickstart.php on line 89

Answer (score 12):

This is the full function, You can use it because It worked fine.

```php
session_start();
$this->load->library('google');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('API Project');
$client->setScopes(implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY)));
//Web Applicaion (json)
$client->setAuthConfigFile('key/client_secret_105219sfdf2456244-bi3lasgl0qbgu5hgedg9adsdfvqmds5c0rkll.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');

$client->setAccessType('offline');       

// Redirect the URL after OAuth
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

// If Access Toket is not set, show the OAuth URL
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
 
    // Prepare the message in message/rfc822
    try {
 
        // The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL

        $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

        $optParams = [];
        $optParams['maxResults'] = 5; // Return Only 5 Messages
        $optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox
        $messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$optParams);
        $list = $messages->getMessages();
        $messageId = $list[0]->getId(); // Grab first Message


        $optParamsGet = [];
        $optParamsGet['format'] = 'full'; // Display message in payload
        $message = $service->users_messages->get('me',$messageId,$optParamsGet);
        $messagePayload = $message->getPayload();
        $headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
        $parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();

        $body = $parts[0]['body'];
        $rawData = $body->data;
        $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
        $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);

        var_dump($decodedMessage);
 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print($e->getMessage());
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
 
}

// If there is no access token, there will show url
if ( isset ( $authUrl ) ) { 
    echo $authUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the sample code I used to develop an email ticketing system. It shows how to retrieve labels, messages, and headers.

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/gmail-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/gmail-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

/**
 * Get list of Messages in user's mailbox.
 *
 * @param  Google_Service_Gmail $service Authorized Gmail API instance.
 * @param  string $userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
 * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @return array Array of Messages.
 */
function listMessages($service, $userId, $optArr = []) {
  $pageToken = NULL;
  $messages = array();
  do {
    try {
      if ($pageToken) {
        $optArr['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $optArr);
      if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) {
        $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
        $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  } while ($pageToken);

  return $messages;
}

function getHeaderArr($dataArr) {
    $outArr = [];
    foreach ($dataArr as $key => $val) {
        $outArr[$val->name] = $val->value;
    }
    return $outArr;
}

function getBody($dataArr) {
    $outArr = [];
    foreach ($dataArr as $key => $val) {
        $outArr[] = base64url_decode($val->getBody()->getData());
        break; // we are only interested in $dataArr[0]. Because $dataArr[1] is in HTML.
    }
    return $outArr;
}

function base64url_decode($data) {
  return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}

function getMessage($service, $userId, $messageId) {
  try {
    $message = $service->users_messages->get($userId, $messageId);
    print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' retrieved.' . "\n";

    return $message;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

function listLabels($service, $userId, $optArr = []) {
    $results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($userId);

    if (count($results->getLabels()) == 0) {
      print "No labels found.\n";
    } else {
      print "Labels:\n";
      foreach ($results->getLabels() as $label) {
        printf("- %s\n", $label->getName());
      }
    }
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$user = 'me';

// Print the labels in the user's account.
listLabels($service, $user);

// Get the messages in the user's account.
$messages = listMessages($service, $user, [
    #'maxResults' => 20, // Return 20 messages.
    'labelIds' => 'INBOX', // Return messages in inbox.
]);

foreach ($messages as $message) {
    print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . "\n";

    $msgObj = getMessage($service, $user, $message->getId());

    $headerArr = getHeaderArr($msgObj->getPayload()->getHeaders());

    echo 'Message-ID: ' . $headerArr['Message-ID'];
    echo "\n";
    echo 'In-Reply-To: ' . (empty($headerArr['In-Reply-To']) ? '' : $headerArr['In-Reply-To']);
    echo "\n";
    echo 'References: ' . (empty($headerArr['References']) ? '': $headerArr['References']);
    echo "\n";

    #print_r($headerArr);

    $bodyArr = getBody($msgObj->getPayload()->getParts());
    echo 'Body: ' . (empty($bodyArr[0]) ? '' : $bodyArr[0]);
}
```

**Reference:**

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify#php

Comment: very close to what I had been looking for, but for some reason I don't get the content of body (the `getParts` is no longer available) if I add filter to the `optArr` param of `listMessages` function,

```$messages = listMessages($service, $user, [
    #'maxResults' => 20, // Return 20 messages.
    'labelIds' => 'INBOX', // Return messages in inbox.
    'q' => 'Marketplace Purchase Complete: New Order'
]);```

Answer (score 2):

I'd start here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list and https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

note that when you get a list of messages only the IDs of those messages are returned then you use the ID with the get method to actually get the message content:

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get message body with php ? $msg->getPayload()->getParts()->getBody(); not able to get content

Comment: php library for gmail api is completed one ?

Comment: That's true , we get only list of messages with its ID. The problem is how to use every ID to get its messageId i.e i am trying to go through the google documentation ,but unable to find any clue.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the excellent answers from @Samphors and @Muffy, here is how you would do this in the MVC world of Symfony

My controller...

```
class GMailController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/g/mail", name="app_g_mail")
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        $code = $request->query->get('code');
        return $this->render('g_mail/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'GMailController',
            'code' => $code
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/g/mail/test", name="app_g_mail_test", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function test(Request $request) : Response
    {
        $filepath = '../client_secret.json';
        $contents = file_get_contents($filepath);
        $client = new Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Gmail_test');
        $client->setAuthConfigFile($filepath);
        $client->addScope('email');
        $client->addScope('https://mail.google.com');
        $client->setRedirectUri('https://localhost:8005/g/mail');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        // Redirect the URL after OAuth
        $code = $request->request->get('code');
        if ($code) {
            error_log('code is set = '.$code);
            $client->authenticate($code);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        }
        
        // If Access Toket is not set, show the OAuth URL
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            error_log('setting access token');
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        } else {
            error_log('creating authorization url');
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            error_log($authUrl);
            return new JsonResponse(['success' => true, 'authUrl' => $authUrl]);
        }
        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
         
            // Prepare the message in message/rfc822
            try {
                $service = new Gmail($client);
                $optParams = [];
                $optParams['maxResults'] = 5; // Return Only 5 Messages
                $optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox
                $messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$optParams);
                $list = $messages->getMessages();
                $messageId = $list[0]->getId(); // Grab first Message
                
                
                $optParamsGet = [];
                $optParamsGet['format'] = 'full'; // Display message in payload
                $message = $service->users_messages->get('me',$messageId,$optParamsGet);
                $messagePayload = $message->getPayload();
                $headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
                $parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();
                
                $body = $parts[0]['body'];
                $rawData = $body->data;
                $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
                $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);
                return new JsonResponse(['success' => true, 'message' => $decodedMessage]);
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                error_log('in exception handler');
                error_log($e);                
                return new JsonResponse(['success' => false, 'error' => $e->__toString()]);
            }
        }
        return new JsonResponse(['success' => false]);
    }
}
```

My twig template...

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}GMail API Bench{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container m-5">
    <div class="row my-2">
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="test-gmail-button">Test GMail API</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-2">
        <h4><b>Authorization:</b></h4>
        <div id="test-authorization">
            <a id="authorization-link" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="gmail-authorization-code" value="{{ code }}">
        {% if code is not null %}
            <span class="text-success"><h4>Authorized</h4></span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="row my-2">
        <h4><b>Results:</b></h4>
        <div id="test-results">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="/static/site/js/gmail_bench.js?v=1.20230126"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

My client-side JavaScript...

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log('gmail_bench.js: in document ready')
})

$('#test-gmail-button').on('click', function(ev) {
    console.log('test gmail');
    let code = $('#gmail-authorization-code').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/g/mail/test',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            code: code
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            if(data.success) {
                if(data.authUrl) {
                    $('#authorization-link').attr('href',data.authUrl);
                    $('#authorization-link').html('Authorize');
                }
                if(data.message) {
                    $('#test-results').empty().append(data.message);
                }
            } else {
                $('#test-results').empty().append(data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            console.log('in test gmail error');
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    })  
})
```

So the way this works is the first post to the test endpoint returns the authorization url.  This is added as a link on the page...

[image: After initial test click...authorize link appears]

Then after authorization, the OAuth2 code is added to the page...

[image: After authorization]

Finally the second click on test butter sends the code and the email contents come back...

[image: After 2nd click of test button]