# Show e-mails from Gmail inbox in SaaS website

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Is there any way to show e-mails from Gmail inbox in my SaaS website in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading messages using gmail api php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503483/reading-messages-using-gmail-api-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The OP edited the question asking for PHP client library.

The [PHP Gmail Google Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) is available but it is still in beta. The code snippets on how to use Google API are in their [Github Repository](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples) but the Gmail API example is not available. This [Gmail API definition file](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/40e4e60f5a9e805fa07feced284e52048fd0e52d/src/Google/Service/Gmail.php) is a good place to get started.

---

You can use the [Google Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/). It has client libraries in [.NET](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-cs), [Java](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java) and [Python](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python). Cite from docs:

> your app can use the API to add Gmail features like:
>
> - Read messages from Gmail
> - Send email messages
> - Modify the labels applied to messages and threads
> - Search for specific messages and threads

An example on how to use the API as per their quick start guide:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run


# Path to the client_secret.json file downloaded from the Developer Console
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

# Check https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

# Location of the credentials storage file
STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')

# Start the OAuth flow to retrieve credentials
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
http = httplib2.Http()

# Try to retrieve credentials from storage or run the flow to generate them
credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)

# Authorize the httplib2.Http object with our credentials
http = credentials.authorize(http)

# Build the Gmail service from discovery
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

# Retrieve a page of threads
threads = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute()

# Print ID for each thread
if threads['threads']:
  for thread in threads['threads']:
    print 'Thread ID: %s' % (thread['id'])
```

For more details, refer to the quick start guide: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503483/reading-messages-using-gmail-api-php) on this matter.

Comment: But I want it for php

Comment: Is this gmail api supports php. if so how can use it?